# List all physical volumes associated to a volume group

Tags: linux, lvm

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I do not see it listed in `vgdisplay`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this format:

```
# pvdisplay -C --separator '  |  ' -o pv_name,vg_name
```

You get something like what I think you're looking for:

```
  PV  |  VG
  /dev/sda2  |  vg_c6srv3
  /dev/sdb2  |  vg_c6srv3
  /dev/sdc2  |  vg_c6srv3
  /dev/sdd1  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sdd2  |  
  /dev/sdd3  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sdd5  |  vg_ora101
  /dev/sde1  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sde2  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sde3  |  
  /dev/sde4  |  vg_ora101
  /dev/sdf1  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sdf2  |  
  /dev/sdf3  |  vg_ora112
  /dev/sdf5  |  vg_ora101
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

`pvdisplay` shows the VG each PV belongs to.

Comment: I've been doing `pvs | grep volume_group` but I thought I might be missing something better suited for this.

Comment: And so does `pvs`, if one wants a more concise form.

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question, it is just as simple as:

`pvdisplay -S vgname=YOUR_VOLUME_GROUP_NAME`

but if you want a simple overview of all physical volumes with its related volume groups:

`pvdisplay -C -o pv_name,vg_name` or even simpler just `pvs`

or that overview filtered on a specific volume group:

`pvdisplay -C -o pv_name,vg_name -S vgname=YOUR_VOLUME_GROUP_NAME`

where:

```
-C|--columns
              Display output in columns, the equivalent of vgs(8).  Options listed are the same as options given in vgs(8).
-o|--options String
              Comma-separated, ordered list of fields to display in columns.
-S|--select String
              Select objects for processing and reporting based on specified criteria.
```

Example output:

```
# pvdisplay -C -o pv_name,vg_name -S vgname=vg_home
  PV         VG
  /dev/sdb   vg_home
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I've found:

```
$ sudo pvdisplay -s -S vgname=<volume_group_name>
  Device "/dev/sdb1" has a capacity of <2.00 GiB
  Device "/dev/sdc1" has a capacity of <10.00 GiB
  Device "/dev/sdd1" has a capacity of <10.00 GiB
```

The key is using the `-s` option (short output) along with `-S vgname=...` to restrict the response to your desired volume group.

Answer (score -1):

```
vgdisplay -v <volume_group_name> 2> /dev/null | awk '/PV Name/ {print $3}'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Just pasting a commandline input isn't always easy to understand.